# jQuery popup error for comment subscription

Tags: php, jquery, datalife-engine

I know there are so many questions about jQuery popup error but my question is very specific to specific module which there is no answer from the author website.

The module is for Datalife Engine 10.0, it was working on previous versions but somehow this jquery function is not adapted to jQuery library 1.8.3 but I think the problem is not with jquery library so that's why I ask here.

The module script is http://codepaste.net/gbrj2j

and jquery code is

```
function commSubs(news_id, user_id, subunsub ){
    $.get(dle_root + "engine/ajax/subscribe.comm.php", { news_id: news_id, user_id: user_id, subunsub: subunsub}, function(data){
        $('#allow_subscribe').text(data.text)
        $('#allow_subscribe').attr('onClick', data.value);
            ShowLoading(data.loading);
            setTimeout('HideLoading(\'\')', 2000);
     }, "json");
    return false;
};

<a onClick="commSubs('{subopt}'); return false;" href="#" id="allow_subscribe">{subscribe}</a>
```

Every time I click and use this module, I always get error message

```
Error: ReferenceError: commSubs is not defined
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but your link http://codepaste.net/mwdarg report this: "You specified a snippet id or link that is invalid and cannot be displayed. Please using the Recent Snippets or My Snippets buttons to look up valid snippets. "

Comment: my apology user2969578, I guess the file was removed because I forgot to login to add the code...and I have edited the link above which is http://codepaste.net/gbrj2j also I have found that the problem seems to be with server running php 5.2.x because this problem doesn't exist in php 5.3.x so I am not sure would it make any senses but it is working on php 5.3.x however, problem is my websites till running php 5.2.x because it's shared host so will have to wait for host provider to upgrade otherwise I am stuck here for the time being...thank you for your reply and hope can find solution. thx